# I broke JSON code

Tags: json, file, config

I have no idea what I am doing but my programmer is sleeping and have phone turned off.
I have a json config file for important server going
the text is like this

```
        "36": {
      "link": "http://www.dpbolvw.net/click-7950848-12234805-1461061905000",
      "name": "Cedok.cz"
  },
    "37": {
      "link": "http://www.vivantis.cz/?d=72815",
      "name": "Vivantis.cz"
  },
    "38": {
      "link": "http://www.tkqlhce.com/click-7950848-12197703-1461744724000",
      "name": "Parfums.cz"
  },
    "99": {
      "link": "http://89.221.208.56/test",
      "name": "Test"
  }
```

I have no idea where exactly I broke the code that my website doesnt function but I did broke it. U just copied one full number and tried to get for a fresh new config setupp..it didnt work..so I deleted the number..and it still does not work.

The code seems perfectly okay to me visually. I messed up the end somehow.

Comment: If you *have no idea* what you're doing, and it's for an *important server*, you should leave it alone until someone who knows what they're doing is available. If you chose not to wait, why should you expect us to fix it? And what benefit to future users here will fixing your personal screwup provide?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might just need another } (closing bracket) at the end of your file. That's just a guess, because it's hard to know without more information.

Comment: You might not just *guess*, because a *guess* is not an *answer*. You might also not attempt to answer questions that make no effort to provide a benefit to future users here, and you should not ever *guess* what might be a solution. The space you used to post is headed *Your Answer*, not *Your Guess* or *Your Stab* at what might work. If there isn't enough information, post a comment to the OP that says so, and once you've obtained the privilege to do so vote to close as unclear until the information is provided. (You can flag for that reason in the meantime and earn benefits from doing so.)

Comment: I recognize that the OP was not using stackoverflow correctly, and that I should have just downvoted his question and moved on. However, he looked like he really needed some assistance and I was confident that my response would help him out - though I couldn't be absolutely sure, because of the lack of context he was providing. Since he accepted my answer, I'm assuming I was correct. I'm happy that I might have helped him out, more so than I am concerned about following protocols, in this case. But thank you for your help to improve the quality of questions and answers on the site.